# INSERT the results of multiple functions but do further processing on the result

Tags: sql, performance, oracle, plsql

I am using a INSERT as SELECT from various tables that uses many functions and relations. the select returns about 10 rows at a time.

The query looks like

```
INSERT INTO EIM_TABLE(certain columns)
select a,b,...,fn(x,y,)
```

Now I need to collect the values returned by `fn(x,y)`, concatenate each of the values into a single variable and carry out further processing based on this.

Performance is a highly critical criteria so want to avoid unnecessary overheads.

Comment: What kind of further processing do you need to do?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the *returning into* clause of the [INSERT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_9014.htm#sthref6444) statement can only be used with the *values* clause so, this isn't going to be quite as pretty as it might be.

If you want to re-use data that you're inserting without selecting it twice you need to place it somewhere it can be re-used. This can either be a [GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE (GTT)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_7002.htm#sthref4994) or a user defined type.

Personally, I prefer a type because I think they're more flexible; what you want to do depends on what processing you have to do afterwards. If you need to perform SQL on the result then a GTT would be more appropriate.

If you want to do something with a user-defined type then combine it with a [BULK COLLECT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e11822/adobjcol.htm#ADOBJ7282); it might look something like the following.

The point is to declare a cursor which is the SELECT statement you want to make; then declare a type that can hold the values of that SELECT statement. You then collect all the data into the type. Once you've done that you can INSERT it anywhere and perform any other manipulations you wish. Generally, it's better to do everything you can in SQL rather than PL/SQL. Don't do the further processing unless you're certain it's quicker to use PL/SQL.

```
declare

   cursor c_stuff is
    select a, b, ..., fn(x, y) as fn
      from somewhere;

   type t__stuff is table of c_stuff%rowtype index by binary_integer;
   t_stuff t__stuff;

   l_new_stuff varchar2(100);

begin

   open c_stuff;
   fetch c_stuff bulk collect into t_stuff;
   close t_stuff;

   forall i in t_stuff.first .. t_stuff.last
      insert into somewhere_else values (t_stuff(i));

   for i in t_stuff.first .. t_stuff.last loop
      l_new_stuff := l_new_stuff || t_stuff(i).fn;
   end loop;

   ...
```

If you go down the GTT route then it looks a bit easier. Create a table that has the same datatypes as returned by your SELECT statement:

```
create global temporary table gtt_stuff (
     a number
   , b ...
   , fn ... )
  on commit delete rows;
```

Then INSERT into this table; you will be able to manipulate the data within the table and utilise it as you would a normal table. Data will persist until the end of the transaction when you use DELETE ROWS and until the end of the session if you specify PRESERVE ROWS.

You say you're concatenating the result of `fn()` so it would probably look like this:

```
select listagg(fn) within group (order by 1)
  into l_new_stuff
  from gtt_stuff;
```

Also note David Aldridge's (great) suggestion in the comments you can also use a multitable INSERT so that you can INSERT into the GTT *and* your table simultaneously:

```
insert all
   into gtt_stuff values (a, ..., fn) -- only necessary columns
   into somewhere_else values (a, b, ..., fn)
select a, b, ..., fn
  from somewhere
```

Comment: I'd suggest going with the GTT route with an enhancement to the process -- use a multitable insert to load both the EIM_TABLE and the global temporary table. Just load the bare minimum required into the GTT (maybe just the function result).

Comment: The multi-table insert is a _great_ idea @David!